# Check is a request is coming from the server local to the app with OWIN

Tags: c#, authorization, owin, hangfire

I need to create an AuthroizationFilter for my Hangfire Dashboard.

Its running on an Azure VM and by design should only accept request from local requests.

I want to create an AuthorizationFilter that validates only those requests from the web browser on the same VM as the web app is running on.

I need to determine this form the OwinContext :-

```
public class MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
     public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
     {
         // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line,
         // `OwinContext` class is the part of the `Microsoft.Owin` package.
         var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

         // Allow all local request to see the Dashboard

         return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue working on a custom `CookieAuthenticationProvider` where only `IOwinContext` was exposed. `context.Request` did not expose an `IsLocal` property, however the following was available:

```
context.Request.Uri.IsLoopback
```

The property was `true` for `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` requests.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the headers in the request context?

```
context.Request.Headers["Referer"]
```

If the value includes localhost or 127.0.0.1 or whatever you're restricting it to.

**CAUTION**: this header can be spoofed.  There may be a better way to limit access to the dashboard.  Does it need internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [HttpRequest.IsLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal(v=vs.110).aspx)? This will tell you if the IP address of the request is the same as the server's IP address.

```
return context.Request.IsLocal;
```